# HoloEverywhere 1.4.2 + Maven Not building the demo Android project

Tags: android, maven-3, maven-plugin, m2eclipse, android-holo-everywhere

I have holoeveywhere "running" in eclipse and I can successully build the "HoloEverywhere Build", as referenced in this link. https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere/wiki/Maven

However, when I try to build the "HoloEverywhere Demo Run", I get this error. Keep in mind that I have the exact same goals as he does which are `android:deploy` & `android:run`. I also select `Skip Tests`.
I made sure I have the correct library referenced in the installed jre's and I have selected the latest jdk in the jre tab for the run configuration.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building HoloEverywhere Demo 1.4.2
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- android-maven-plugin:3.5.0:deploy (default-cli) @ demo ---
[INFO] C:\Users\Akhil\Downloads\Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\platform-tools\aapt.exe [dump, xmltree, C:\Users\Akhil\HoloEverywhere\demo\target\demo-1.4.2.apk, AndroidManifest.xml]
[INFO] Found 0 devices connected with the Android Debug Bridge
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Skipping HoloEverywhere Demo
[INFO] This project has been banned from the build due to previous failures.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.801s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Jan 20 16:22:07 EST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/18M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.5.0:deploy (default-cli) on project demo: No online devices attached. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Is it because my emulator's not launching? I've tried to launch the emulator through the AVD Manager itself and it did not work.
What's wrong with my configuration? And how can I fix it?
Any tips are much appreciated.

Thanks!

**Edit**

Here is my windows environment Path variable
Name: Path
Value: C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\bin;C:\Users\Akhil\Downloads\Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\platform-tools

Here is the screenshot of my run configuration. Don't worry, I use the jdk.
[image: HoloEverywhere Demo Run - Run Configuration]

Comment: I think the "Found 0 devices connected with the Android Debug Bridge" means android-maven-plugin might not be available to find the emulator devices on your machine. Have you googled for similar error messages?

Comment: Yes I have tried all sorts of tricks with adb. I have googled it and haven't gotten any luck.

Comment: I've updated the post with my run configuration if you want to see. I think I'm going to try to change the directory of the sdk.

Answer (score 0):

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874305/android-maven-not-starting-emulator)

> Run mvn android:emulator-start before mvn android:deploy. The maven plugin cannot deploy to an emulator that does not exist.

Comment: Tried that. Doesn't even start up an emulator, it has never done so. And the build is a failure again.